# application don't asks for enabeling notifications in app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, push-notification

I am trying to build an app that is using push notifications. I did all the steps concerning certificates, app-id's, provisionings profiles. Then in my app I added this piece of code in the applicationsDidFinishWithLaunchingOptions.

```
  NSLog(@"tille here");
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
    UIRemoteNotificationType enabledTypes = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes];
```

But I don't get the pop up that asks for it.

Can anybody help?

Kind regards

Comment: does the registration fail or succeed?

Comment: Are you running your app in the simulator or on a device?  If it's in the simulator the pop won't appear.

Comment: I'm running it on device. And what do you mean with registration fail or succeed ?

Comment: Have you added following - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error

Comment: Are you sure you have configured the app's push notification for your app in the App IDs section? And you can have a try to regenerate a provisioning profile, delete old profile and then add/use the new profile to build the app(Of course remember to delete old one from your device and clean up the project).